# How to check if Matomo was loaded or possibly blocked?

Tags: javascript, matomo

I'm looking for a JavaScript variable, function or something to check for,
if the Matomo tracking script wasn't successfully loaded or probably blocked (by a Tracker- or Ad-blocker browser extension, Pi-hole, etc.).

I already have something similar for Google Analytics, which I want to extend:

```js
const ehi_ga = window[window['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] || 'ga'];
if (typeof ehi_ga !== 'function' || ehi_ga.loaded !== true || !ehi_ga.create) {
    return false;
}
```

How can I extend this, to check for the existence/state of the Matomo script?

Answer (score 1):

What I went with for now is the following:

```js
const ehi_ga = window[window['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] || 'ga'];
const gaProbablyNotLoaded = typeof ehi_ga !== 'function' || ehi_ga.loaded !== true || !ehi_ga.create;

const matomo = window['Matomo'];
const matomoProbablyNotLoaded = typeof matomo !== 'object' || matomo.initialized !== true || !matomo.trigger;

if (gaProbablyNotLoaded && matomoProbablyNotLoaded) {
    return false;
}
```

I'm just leaving this here for future reference.